# How would you combined sort-by and filter in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have a collection of strings, and I want to return all strings over 4 characters long, sorted by shortest string first.

You could solve that with something along the lines of:

```
(def strings ["this" "is" "super" "cool" "everybody" "isn't" "clojure" "great!?!?"])
(sort-by count < (filter #(> (count %) 4) strings))
;; > ("super" "isn't" "clojure" "everybody" "great!?!?")
```

Notice we're using `count` twice. This is probably fine here, but what if `count` wasn't `count`? What if instead of `count` we called `super-expensive-function` that we'd really rather not run more than absolutely necessary?

So:

- We have a collection of things
- We want to return an ordered collection of things
- Filtered and sorted using the result of a computationally expensive function which should only be called once per thing

Is there an existing function that does this, or do I need to build my own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to pair up each item together with its expensive-to-compute property, then filter and sort, then discard the parameter:

```
(->> strings
     (map (juxt identity count))
     (filter (fn [[_ c]] (> c 4)))
     (sort-by peek)
     (map first))
```

If computing the property in question is really all that expensive, the overhead of allocating the vectors should pretty much vanish.

Comment: I would use `(sort-by second)`, because I think that's a bit more obvious than `peek`.

Comment: @mange Well, I actually find `peek` obvious enough when I know the data structure involved (though of course technically speaking it's meant to be a stack/queue operation and on lists -- the other standard stack implementation -- it's actually equivalent to `first`...). Here I'm mostly using it to avoid allocating the two intermediate seqs needed by `second`. Another option: `#(nth % 1)` (efficient in all cases). Yet another: use short lists for pairing and `first` / `second` for accessing the members of the pair (with the sorting key going in the `first` slot).

Comment: for readability, how about: `(->> strings (map (fn [s] {:string s :count (count s)})) (filter #(> (:count %) 4)) (sort-by :count) (map :string))`. A short hash map is not much more expensive than a vector.

Comment: FYI since I realised I only really care about the first result of that list I ended up implementing it as an anon func to reduce, which was significantly faster. There are so many places in Clojure where the pretty idiomatic code performs so slow compared to fast ugly code, it's sad :-(

Comment: (e.g. (map (partial foo x) list-of-ys) is much slower than (map (fn [y] (foo x y)) list-of-ys) for example.. /rant)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the JIT-compiler can figure out that this expensive, intermediate result is cacheable between the two operations? It's worth a try to rule this possibility out given the increased complexity in manually caching the result. I would run performance test a few times with for various solutions with time measurement like this:

```
(time (dotimes [_ 1e5] ...))
```

Comment: Good point, you could use memoize, either the standard core implementation or one of the more flexible solutions

Comment: Yup, core.memoize is great!

Answer (score 0):

You can pair-up using group-by and do the aggregation and filtering with list comprehension.

```
(for [[c sv] (sort-by first (group-by count strings)) :when (> c 4) s sv] s)
```